# Counting the number of moves for sorting an array if only unit shift are allowed

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

So, I have an array containing integers. I need to sort it. However, the only operation I can perform is a unit shift. That is, I can move the last element of the sequence to its beginning.

```
          `a1, a2, ..., an → an, a1, a2, ..., an - 1.`
```

what is the minimum number of operations that I need to sort the sequence?

The number of integers in the array can be upto 10^5. And each integer individual value can be 10^5 too. Also, if array is already sorted, print 0 else if array cannot be sorted by unit shifts, print -1.

The solution that I thought of:

1. Check if array is sorted or not.
2. If array is sorted, print 0 else
3. Set count = 0
4. Rotate array by one unit and increment count.
5. Check if array is sorted: if yes, print count and break, else
6. repeat steps 4-5 till count < (total integers in array).

Now, the above solution has a time complexity of O(n^2). Because, I am checking for each individual element if array is sorted and this checking takes O(n) time, and I have n elements, so that makes it O(n^2).

Can anyone suggest me some other better approach?
Thanks!

PS: I tried really hard thinking of some other approach. I reached uptill counting inversions, but that doesn't really help.

Comment: So the only inputs that this "sort" routine can sort are sorted arrays that may have been rotated by some amount, and all you're trying to do is undo the rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate the array, find the first index `i` such that `arr[i] > arr[i+1]` (If there is no such index, we are done since array is already sorted), then check if `arr[i+1],...,arr[n]` is sorted, and if `arr[n] <= arr[1]`. If it is, it can be done by doing `n-i` rotations.

Otherwise, there is no solution.

Time complexity is O(n), space complexity O(1).

---

**Appendix:** Correctness of the algorithm:

Claim 1:

> If the array cannot be splitted to two arrays
>   `arr[1],arr[2],..,arr[i]` and `arr[i+1],...,arr[n]` - both sorted,
>   then there is no solution.

Proof:

Let's assume `i` is the first index where `arr[i] > arr[i+1]`, and let `j` be some other index such that `arr[j] > arr[j+1]`, j!=i. There must be such because `arr[i+1],...,arr[n]` is unsorted.

By definition, while `j+1` was not "unit shifted", the array is unsorted.

Immidiately after it was shifted, it is still not sorted since `arr[i] > arr[i+1]`, and after another shift, `arr[j]` is again before `arr[j+1]`, and violating the sorted order. 

Thus, the array cannot be sorted.

Claim 2:

> Assume an array that can be splitted to two sorted array
>   `arr[1],...,arr[i]`, and `arr[i+1],...,arr[n]`. 
> Also assume
>   `arr[i] > arr[i+1]`. 
> Then, the array can be "unit shifted" into
>   sorted one, if and only if `arr[n] <= arr[1]`.

Proof:

`<---`

The array is not sorted, so at least one unit shift must be done. This unit shift places `arr[n]` before `arr[1]`, and the array will never be sorted unless `arr[n]<=arr[1]`

`--->`

Assume `arr[n]<=arr[1]`, then by shifting `arr[i+1],...,arr[n]`, we get the following array:

```
arr[i+1],arr[i+2],...,arr[n],arr[1],arr[2],...,arr[i]
```

Note that `arr[i+1]<= arr[i+2] <= .... <= arr[n]` since we assumed it is sorted.

Similarly `arr[1]<=arr[2]<=...<=arr[i]`

Also note `arr[n] <= arr[i]`, from assumption.

By joining the 3 above inequalities we get:

```
arr[i+1] <= arr[i+2] <= ... <= arr[n] M= arr[1] <= arr[2] <= ... <= arr[i]
```

The above is by definition a sorted array, which concludes the proof for the claim.

Claim 3:

> The algorithm is correct

By applying claim1,claim2 and handling specifically the case where array is already sorted, we get that:

The array can be sorted using "unit shifts" if and only if: It is already sorted, OR conditions of claim2 applies, and this concludes the proof.

**QED**

Comment: If I give input as `1 3 2`, then the value of `i` will be `1`, going by your logic, the answer will come out to be `2`, however, the actual answer to the above input is `-1`. That is, it cannot be sorted by unit shifts. Also, the number of rotations will be `n-i-1`.

Comment: @Elliot A small mistake, sorry. It is supposed to be `arr[n] <= arr[1]` - not `arr[n] < arr[i]` (Note that the proof at the appendix did use the correct inequality). The algorithm (with this fix) is correct, since I proved it.

Comment: @Elliot Also note, I used 1-based index (i.e. `arr[1]` is the first element, not `arr[0]`) (sorry if it is confusing, used to much matlab of late, and it's pretty much a habit now)

Comment: Kudos. Amazing proof and well written. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated. :)